# Shopify cart.item_count not updating using AJAX onclick function

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to update the **Shopify** cart `onclick`. It's working but when I try to update cart count without page refresh with cart add `success: function` it's not working. Below is my code.

```
$(function(){
    $('.varients-item').on('click', function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            data: {
                quantity: 1,
                id: $(this).attr("data-variant")
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {  
                //alert('Item added to cart');
                $('.cart-item-count').html(cart.item_count);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the `console` error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
$(function(){
    var cartCount = {{ cart.item_count }};
    $('.varients-item').on('click', function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            data: {
                quantity: 1,
                id: $(this).attr("data-variant")
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/cart.json',
                    success: function(cart){
                        cartCount++;
                        $('.cart-item-count').html(cartCount);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you are calling `cart.item_count`, but `cart` is not defined. It's written in the error response.

You are passing `data` as the callback argument here `success: function (data)`, so you should call `data.item_count` instead.

**BUT** `cart/add.js` does not return the JSON for the cart, but the added product JSON. You need to make a second request to `cart.js` in order to get the cart object!

So your code should look something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.varients-item').on('click', function(){
      var obj = $(this);
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/cart/add.js',
          data: {
              quantity: 1,
              id: $(this).attr("data-variant")
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function () {  
              $.ajax({
                url: '/cart.js',
                success: function(cart){
                  $('.cart-item-count').html(cart.item_count);
                }
              })
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I add your code but found new error http://prntscr.com/sgvkxj

Comment: . My jQuery version `3.4.1`. When I replace with `1.12.4` no error but cart count not updating on click.

Comment: Your solution isn't working for me. But you gave me clue how to fix. Below is my ans.

Comment: Solution might work but you need to add json format param (dataType: 'json',) for the GET as you do for your POST function to avoid error.

Comment: @AliceGirard you are not required to pass dataType in this case, since we are requesting a JS route and jQuery ajax will automatically understand that we expect JSON as response. Please refer to the docs here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ where it's stated that the default response type can be guessed. If we request a HTML page with JSON response that will be another story.

Comment: @drip Maybe but with jQuery last version, this is only way to avoid silent error mentioned , it actually worked. Got case last week.